# How do I embed chapter metadata in mp3 files in C#?

Tags: c#, mp3, id3

I'm trying to make a tool to edit and embed chapter markings in mp3 files (for podcasting) through [this](http://id3.org/id3v2-chapters-1.0) spec.

All of the libraries I've found so far do not support the CHAP or CTOC frames, nor can I figure out a way to make them work with custom frames.  NTagLite seems to be my favorite so far, but I am having trouble building the source on VS2017 to try splicing in my own methods for different frame types, and at the end of the day I'm not a very advanced programmer so using a ByteStream manually is a bit over my head.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?  Anyone with experience here?  Am I just missing the calls in these libraries and that functionality is all already there?

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Audio Tools Library for .NET (https://github.com/Zeugma440/atldotnet) supports ID3v2 chapters (CTOC / CHAP frames) reading and writing.

Sample code from the wiki below :

```
using System;
using ATL.AudioData;
using System.Collections.Generic;

AudioDataManager theFile = new AudioDataManager(AudioData.AudioDataIOFactory.GetInstance().GetDataReader(<fileLocation>));

Dictionary<uint, ChapterInfo> expectedChaps = new Dictionary<uint, ChapterInfo>();
TagData theTag = new TagData();
theTag.Chapters = new List<ChapterInfo>();
expectedChaps.Clear();

ChapterInfo ch = new ChapterInfo();
ch.StartTime = 123;
ch.StartOffset = 456;
ch.EndTime = 789;
ch.EndOffset = 101112;
ch.UniqueID = "";
ch.Title = "aaa";
ch.Subtitle = "bbb";
ch.Url = "ccc\0ddd";

theTag.Chapters.Add(ch);
expectedChaps.Add(ch.StartTime, ch);

ch = new ChapterInfo();
ch.StartTime = 1230;
ch.StartOffset = 4560;
ch.EndTime = 7890;
ch.EndOffset = 1011120;
ch.UniqueID = "002";
ch.Title = "aaa0";
ch.Subtitle = "bbb0";
ch.Url = "ccc\0ddd0";

theTag.Chapters.Add(ch);
expectedChaps.Add(ch.StartTime, ch);

// Persists the chapters
theFile.UpdateTagInFile(theTag, MetaDataIOFactory.TAG_ID3V2);

// Reads them
theFile.ReadFromFile(null, true);

foreach (ChapterInfo chap in theFile.ID3v2.Chapters)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(chap.Title + "(" + chap.StartTime + ")");
}
```

Comment: It worked  -only- when, on a fresh mp3 file, i added the theTag.Title. Not adding it resulted in chapters not being added!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a library that will do this for you, you might be able to do it yourself.  First, define some object which encapsulates the ID3 tag's chapter-related metadata/frames:

```
public class ChapterFrame : Frame
{
    private Header Header { get; set; }
    private string ElementId { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan StartOffset { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan EndOffset { get; set; }
    private List<ChapterFrame> Subframes = new List<ChapterFrame>();
}
```

Then write some method (something like `ChapterFrame.ToByteArray()`):

```
public byte[] ToByteArray(ChapterFrame frame) {
    return new byte[]; 
}
```

... that takes each of the `ChapterFrame`'s fields and flattens them out into a serialized array of bytes, conformant with the ID3 v2.3/2.4 Chapter Frame Addendum standards:

[image: from "ID3v2 Chapter Frame Addendum", C. Newell, 2 December 2005]

Now that you've got a new frame, you can scan through the ID3 tag to figure out where to insert the new frame.

Please note that I'm definitely not an expert here - this is just a guess.